# elasticsearch incompatible-snapshots purpose

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

`Incompatible-snapshots` file has appeared on amazon-s3 after a couple of backups using elasticsearch-curator.

What is the purpose of that file? Should I remove it? What information it provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file contains a list of all snapshots ids, that are no longer compatible with the current version of the cluster. Is it possible you have stored snapshots in that repository that span more than two major versions of elasticsearch?